# PHP: create an array with the whole database data

Tags: php, mysql, database, multidimensional-array

I want to "automatically" load ALL my database data into `$db[]` and/or `$_SESSION['db']`. Thus, I just have to load this code once, instead of loading bits and pieces throughout the website.

I was able to query the meta data and raw data, my problem is creating the array.

Let's say I have a table `temp` with columns `name` and `age` I want to be able to do something like this: `echo $db['temp']['name'] . "'s age is: " . $db['temp']['age'];` -Obviously I have lots of tables with lots of columns. This is just an example

```
<?php
$dbn = "db_name";
$dbu = "db_user";
$dbp = "db_password";
$hst = 'db_host';

$dbc = mysql_connect($hst,$dbu,$dbp);


$sql_metadata = 
"SELECT `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_NAME` as 'table' , `COLUMNS`.`COLUMN_NAME` as 'column'
FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS
WHERE `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '$dbn'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC , `COLUMNS`.`COLUMN_NAME` ASC";

$dbq = mysql_query($sql_metadata, $dbc);
while( $meta = mysql_fetch_array($dbq) )
{
    $sql_rawdata = "SELECT `$meta['column']` FROM `$dbn`.`$meta['table']`";
    $dbq2 = mysql_query($sql_rawdata);
    foreach( ($raw = mysql_fetch_array($dbq2)) as $value) )
    {
        $db = array
                ( 
                $meta['table'] => array( $meta['column'] => $value)
                );
    }
}
print_r($db);
?>
```

Comment: It's highly unrecommended if you're on a shared host, anybody on the server can read your database from `/tmp/`

Comment: How did you get to the idea that his db is stored in the tmp/-folder? AFAIK all tables are stored in a subfolger called "data" in the MySQL installation folder...

Comment: Out of curiosity; what's the purpose of this?

Comment: @Corsair, OP mentioned he wants to store in `$_SESSION`, session data are stored in `/tmp/`

Comment: @repox Instead of adding php's mysql functions and code on every page, I want to have the database's data available across all '*.php' requests in "one single shot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your array before going into the loop and then fill it:

```
$db = array();

$sql_metadata = 
"SELECT DISTINCT `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_NAME` as 'table' 
FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS 
WHERE `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '$dbn'";

$dbq = mysql_query($sql_metadata, $dbc);
while( $meta = mysql_fetch_array($dbq) )
{
    $sql_rawdata = "SELECT `$meta['column']` FROM `$dbn`.`$meta['table']`";
    $dbq2 = mysql_query($sql_rawdata);
    $raw = mysql_fetch_array($dbq2);

    foreach($raw as $value )
    {
        $db[$meta['table']][$meta['column']][] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($db);
```

For explanation: You create a multi-dimensional array with the table name pointing towards the column names. the [] at the end of the array tells PHP to store the content of $value into a new array element of table=>column.

THis would be an easier way to fetch the whole data:

```
    $sql_rawdata = "SELECT * FROM `".$dbn."`.`".$meta['table']."`";
    $dbq2 = mysql_query($sql_rawdata);

    while($raw = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbq2)){
        foreach($raw as $column => $value )
        {
            $db[$meta['table']][$column][] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still have the same coding error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ...db.php on line 21`

Comment: You did not mention that in your first post ;-) And i did not see the error in first place, this is a result of your brackets in the foreach, the loop doesen't even create the variable $value. Look at my edits.

Comment: I should had been more specific instead of just saying "...my problem is creating the array" :P the error is coming from this line: `$sql_rawdata = "SELECT $meta['column'] FROM $dbn.$meta['table']";`

Comment: Try to add explicit seperators, i guess PHP isn't able to concat the variable with the db-name properly:    `$sql_rawdata = "SELECT ".$meta['column']." FROM ".$dbn.".".$meta['table'];`

Comment: that got rid of the error and the code is working...partially. I am able to call a value with `echo $db['temp']['name'][0]` whoever it is only giving giving me the first record of the table. I think it would be best to replace the `$raw = mysql_fetch_array($dbq2);
` with `while( $raw = mysql_fetch_array($dbq2) )...` to loop through all the records

Comment: Yes you'r right, but i found another error: you would also have to fetch ALL colums if you want to have all the data in your array. i modified your code a bit to select everything in the table and store it in the array. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` makes sure that you will only fetch the columns by name and not by number AND name as `mysql_fetch_array()` does. as a result you can fill your array row by row, which should result in a performance improvement as well.

Comment: Looks like we are on the same page. I was going on the same direction. At the same time, I learned something new =). I had no idea about `mysql_fetch_assoc` and it's use. The one problem I noticed is that is is inserting the same data twice.

Comment: I found the problem and a solution. Since we are now pulling the whole table's data instead of column by column. `information_schema` is giving me an x number of tables of the same name with the column name as well. We need to change $sql_metadata query to this: `$sql_metadata = 
"SELECT DISTINCT \`COLUMNS\`.\`TABLE_NAME\` as 'table' 
FROM \`information_schema\`.COLUMNS
WHERE \`COLUMNS\`.\`TABLE_SCHEMA\` = '$dbn'"`